# Is UDTF possible in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I used UDF functions in dataframe . like

```
def manhattanUDF(firstPoint:linalg.Vector) = udf((features: linalg.Vector) => {
    firstPoint.toArray.zip(features.toArray).foldLeft(0.0) { case (sum, (v1, v2)) => {
       sum + Math.abs(v1 - v2)
    }}
  })
```

I dont know how to use UDTF in spark ? Pease help me with an example .

Comment: I've never heard of UDTF in Spark. You can easily do this using an UDF returning an Array of objects and then `explode` the results in DataFrame API

Comment: Could you explain what UDTF is?

Answer (score 1):

explode and posexplode functions are UDTF functions and DataFrame API supports these functions. But there is no custom implementation for UDTF in Spark.